# PostgreSQL: Find record within distance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

For my application, I've an User where each one is geolocated. What I want to achieve, is to retrieve User who are within a distance (e.g. User where distance >= 1000 and distance <= 2000).

My user have a `longitude` and a `latitude` field.

So far, here's my request :

```
select(%{users.*,
  ST_DISTANCE(
    ST_GeographyFromText(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || users.longitude || ' ' || users.latitude || ')'
    ),
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)')
  ) as distance
} % [longitude, latitude])
.where(%{
  ST_DISTANCE(
    ST_GeographyFromText(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || users.longitude || ' ' || users.latitude || ')'
    ),
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)')
  ) > %d AND
  ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeographyFromText(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || users.longitude || ' ' || users.latitude || ')'
    ),
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(%f %f)'),
    %d
  )
} % [longitude, latitude, 15, longitude, latitude, distance_in_meters])
```

This is pretty ugly : can you help me ?

Comment: Not really a proper answer, but you could use a BETWEEN condition since your condition is inclusive. Also, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326) is faster than what you have, according to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/which-function-for-creating-a-point-in-postgis/58630#58630

Answer (score 1):

You should store your data as a new `geog` column, with a spatial index:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN geog geography(Point, 4326);
UPDATE users SET geog = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
CREATE INDEX users_geog_idx ON users USING gist (geog);
```

You may also want to drop the longitude and latitude columns, as they are redundant. Coordinates can be obtained from point geometries using ST_X and ST_Y.

---

To find records that are within a specified range, use a regular SELECT statement to capture the outer distance, then an [EXCEPT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT) to remove the inner distance.

```
WITH poi AS (
  SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%longitude, %latitude), 4326)::geography AS poi
)
SELECT users.*, ST_Distance(geog, poi) AS distance
FROM users
JOIN poi ON ST_DWithin(geog, poi, %outer_dist)
EXCEPT SELECT users.*, ST_Distance(geog, poi) AS distance
FROM users
JOIN poi ON ST_DWithin(geog, poi, %inner_dist);
```

The parameters are marked with `%`, which you can reformat for your application.

Comment: Why did you propose to use Geography instead of Geometry ? I've read some article about the speed of Geography which is slower than Geometry.

Comment: @cappie013 your question used geography. You could also use `ST_DWithin(g1, g2, false)` to approximate distances on a sphere, which are faster than distances on spheroids (default). ST_Distance on geometries works in Cartesian space, which is fastest, but I don't recommend this unless you have projected points all in (e.g.) one UTM zone.